# Request specs: "missing template error" only when ran in a group, file or suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Strange problem. I have many request specs that fail on **get requests** (index, show, edit, update).

The exception is raised by :

```
actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:53
```

Which does not find the necessary template.

However, all these examples pass when I run them individually. The templates exist. They all fail **but the first one** when I run them *within a test file or a whole suite*.

Last thing, this problem began to occur after I upgraded Rails from 5.0.2 to 5.1.1. I tried to get back to a commit before this upgrade, and everything went back to normal. I looked in the *Rails release notes* but did not found anything relevant...

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer !

For some reason, I happened to have this line in my **spec/rails_helper.rb**:

```
config.include RSPec::Rails::ViewRendering
```

Which, I think, came from an old tutorial on view specs. Unfortunately, I was not able to find which one (tutorial) it was...

Anyway, I just remove this line, and everything went OK! My request specs pass, even when ran in a suite or whole file. (and my view specs also pass)

Hope this could be useful to anyone.